# ScrollView.js: Property body[41] of BlockStatement expected node to be of a type ["Statement"] but instead got "AssignmentExpression"

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

I am facing the problem while making apk using expo build:android.
After getting it I have downgrade Babel 7.15 to 7.14 but same error is showing.
I am also using the latest version of expo-cli i.e. expo-cli 4.10.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to solve this issue.

1. Best simple way,
   This issue occurs due to @babel/core.
   if you have any other project which are working well, copy @babel folder from node_modules and past it on the project you are facing issue.
2. Or you can download proper @babel from Here
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-z_4H_z4x075unZqZD41WYUwY_hsrKox/view
3. Downgrade babel version.

First of all remove the current @babel/core from the package.json
Now just install older version of babel with this command.
npm install –save-dev @babel/ core@7.12.9
Now you are able to run your project without any error.